# Derivation of Fokker-Planck equation from Langevin equation

Tags: path-integral, stochastic-processes

I have been trying for a long while to wrap my head around this step in the derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation in Appendix 8 of Nigel Goldenfeld's "Lectures On Phase Transitions And The Renormalization Group":
[image]

after which it says: "where we integrated by parts and used the expression (8.42) for the probability distribution."
With (8.42) being:

[image]
(ignore the blue highlighting).

My question is, how is equation (A8.2) derived?
And what is the D sign referring to: the variance of the distribution $P_{\zeta}$ (diffusion constant) or is it just indicating that the functional integral is over $\zeta$?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: $D\zeta$ is the measure of integration, while a $D$ alone indeed refers to the variance of $P_\zeta$. Try to do the functional derivative of $P_\zeta$ with respect to $\zeta$, and, upon integrating by parts, observe the middle equality of A8.2.

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed your hint and got the result A8.2 but only under the assumption that  $\int D\zeta \frac{\delta}{\delta\zeta}(F P_\zeta) = 0$. What is the reason for this?

Comment: I suppose that this is because $\int D\zeta \frac{\delta}{\delta \zeta} (FP_\zeta) = \left[FP_\zeta \right]_{\zeta(t,\textbf{r})=-\infty}^{\zeta(t,\textbf{r})=\infty}$ (or something like that), where I guessed that the functional integral is a continuous product of regular integrals from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. $\zeta$ is a symmetric noise term, so I reckon the integral should become zero regardless of $F$. Thank you again. Stay around, the world needs you.